# Check if not in list - more conditions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists with not fixed number of items, e. g.:

```
data=['sun','stars','moon','supermoon','planet','comet','galaxy']

forbidden=['mo','st','lax']
```

I need to print only those items of `data` which do not contain any of the strings listed in `forbidden`. In this case the output would be

```
sun
planet
comet
```

What I tried is

```
print [x for x in data if forbidden not in x ]
```

which works only for one condition (one item in `forbidden` list)

Is there any way how to check all the conditions at once?

In case I knew the number of items in `forbidden` I could use

```
print [x for x in data if forbidden[0] not in x and forbidden[1] not in x]
```

but it does not work with unknown number of items.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `all`:

```
data=['sun','stars','moon','supermoon','planet','comet','galaxy']
forbidden=['mo','st','lax']
print([i for i in data if all(c not in i for c in forbidden)])
```

Output:

```
['sun', 'planet', 'comet']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is more of a functional approach:

```
from itertools import product
from operator import contains, itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)

p = product(data, forbidden)
f = filter(lambda tup: contains(*tup), p)
set(data).difference(set(map(first, f)))

{'comet', 'planet', 'sun'}  # order is not preserved here if that matters
```

Edit: If the data is large this will handle it more gracefully and return results faster